# Site turned to maintenance mode without changing any settings

Tags: 6, maintenance-mode

I have a client who's site maintenance came up without anyone touching it. What would cause something like this?

I have theories that it's the backup module. Would that be possible?

I just went and turned maintenance mode off last night and just now but the maintenance mode eventually goes back up.

I reviewed this thread but it wasn't related: [How to access the admin pages for a site stuck in maintenance mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234/site-stuck-in-maintenance-mode)

Since, I'm pretty sure that clean url's are turned on already.

Comment: What is the value of the "site_offline" variable? You can find that with `select * from variable where name like "site_offline"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal will [show a site as offline if it cannot connect to the database](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/_db_error_page/6), so you may want to check that the database is up and running.